# Counting letters in a string by type in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to find out how many lettes/numbers, punctuation marks and '$' sings are in a string.
I am trying a set of 3 regexes with preg_match_all:

Let's say I have a string such as `$string = "abcde!@#$%$$";`

for the count of $: I tried

`$check = preg_match_all("/(\$)/", $string, $matches);`

which should give me 3 matches. But a var_dump of $matches give me this here:

`array (  0 =>   array (    0 > '',  ),  1 =>   array (    0 => '',  ),)`

similarly, I tried to match all letters and punctuation with the patterns `'/(\w)/'` and `'/(\W)/'` respectively, but there I do not get any matches. Why?

Btw I know that \W also matches '$'.

Comment: List all needed characters manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes, otherwise PHP thinks you want to interpolate given the dollar sign:

```
$check = preg_match_all('/(\$)/', $string, $matches);
                        ^      ^
```

That should do. Also you don't need the capturing group: `'/\$/'`

I don't see a problem with the other regex. `'/\W/'` outputs 7, and `'/\w/'` outputs 5.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I pasted the others here wrong, I also used double quotes in the code itself - and some typos.... Since the first one already failed I did not investigate the others for the typos close enough. now all works!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine this into 1 RegEx: `/([\w])|([!,\.])|(\$)/`.

This will match `1`: words (alphanumeric), `2`: punctuation (`!`, `,`, `.`, or whatever you add to the class), and `3`: dollar signs.  Then you can loop through `preg_match_all()` to get the counts:

```
<?php
$alphanumeric = $punctuation = $dollar = 0;

if(preg_match_all('/([\w])|([!,\.])|(\$)/', 'abcde!@#$%$$', $matches)) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach($matches[$i] as $match) {
            if($match)
              $count++;
        }

        switch($i) {
            case 1: $alphanumeric = $count; break;
            case 2: $punctuation = $count; break;
            case 3: $dollar = $count; break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($alphanumeric); // int(5)
var_dump($punctuation); // int(1)
var_dump($dollar); // int(3)
```

Obviously, the 3 matching groups (`[\w]`, `[!,\.]`, `\$`) can be modified or added to depending on your needs.

Comment: I really like this code because it does only one preg_match for all items! Thaks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "abcde!@#$%$$1234567";

$count_negated = array(
  'ALPHA' =>  '[^[:alpha:]]+',
  'ALNUM' =>  '[^[:alnum:]]+',
  'DIGITS' => '\D+',
  'DOLLAR' => '[^$]+',
  'PUNCT' =>  '[^[:punct:]]+'
);

foreach($count_negated AS $k => $v)
{
  echo "There are ".
        strlen(preg_replace('~'.$v.'~', "", $str))." ".$k.
        " in my string<br>";
}
```

*output*:

```
There are 5 ALPHA in my string
There are 12 ALNUM in my string
There are 7 DIGITS in my string
There are 3 DOLLAR in my string
There are 7 PUNCT in my string
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware about the matches you use there, gotta look also into those.

Comment: @uncovery `[:these:]` are [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).